# RBAC for GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to use RBAC policies in my GKE clusters, so i need to enforce view role to a group and admin role to another group. I have 2 groups created abc@example.com and def@example.com for the RBAC policies, will i be able to reference them directly in my ClusterRoleBinding yaml file like:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: view-role
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Group
  name: "abc@example.com"
```

Or should I enable "Google Groups for RBAC" and create a group "gke-security-groups@YOUR_DOMAIN" (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control#rolebinding) and add the above groups to it and then create RBAC rule in the GKE cluster ?

I created the above ClusterRoleBinding nothing sort off changed(without enabling the "Google Groups for RBAC"), please let me know how to apply RBAC accesses to a group in GKE cluster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that you already created/set up your google groups. If not, see this link to [Configure Google Groups for RBAC](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control#groups-setup-gsuite) and you must update your cluster to enable RBAC feature.

To update an existing cluster to [Enable the Google Groups for RBAC feature](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control#groups-create-cluster), perform the following steps in Google Cloud Console:

1. Go to the Google Kubernetes Engine page in Cloud Console.
2. Go to Google Kubernetes Engine
3. Beside the cluster you want to edit, click more_vert Actions, then click edit Edit.
4. Under the Details tab, for the Google Groups for RBAC field, click edit Edit Google Groups for RBAC.
5. Select the Enable Google Groups for RBAC checkbox.
6. Enter your security group name.
7. Click Save changes.